# Fastest min-cut (max-flow) algorithm in actual practice on small weighted DAG

Tags: c++, directed-acyclic-graphs, max-flow

I want to solve the min-cut problem on a lot of small DAGS (8-12 nodes,20-60 edges) very quickly. It looks like the best solution is to solve the max-flow and deduce a cut from that. There are quite a few max-flow algorithms with both theoretical and empirical timing comparisons available, but these all assume what's interesting is performance as the graphs get larger and larger. It's also often mentioned that set-up times for complicated data structures used can be quite big. So given a careful, optimized implementation (probably in C++) which algorithm turns out to be fastest for initialising and running on small graphs? (My naive assumption is that Edmonds-Karp is probably as simple in terms of data-structures so will beat more complicated algorithms, but that's just a guesstimate.)